# Quarkus/Vert.x attempting to connect to proxy over SSL

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus, vert.x

I have a Quarkus (3.2.4) service using keycloak (22.0.1) authorization services and "quarkus.oidc" that I am trying to get to use our Squid proxy.  The problem I can see in the javax.net.ssl logs is that vert.x-eventloop is attempting a SSL connection to squid. I thought the problem may have been leaving http2 enabled with vert.x, but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue.  I can see in the logs where it connects to the keycloak oidc discovery endpoint and /certs endpoint before continuing onto the client hello to Squid.  How do I stop vert.x/Quarkus from attempting SSL with my proxy?

javax.net.debug:

```
2023-08-23 13:14:18.798,"javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|71|vert.x-eventloop-thread-1|2023-08-23 13:14:18.798 GMT|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:213|READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 2272"
2023-08-23 13:14:18.801,javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|71|vert.x-eventloop-thread-1|2023-08-23 13:14:18.801 GMT|SSLCipher.java:1675|Plaintext after DECRYPTION (
...
2023-08-23 13:14:20.523,javax.net.ssl|ALL|10|main|2023-08-23 13:14:20.523 GMT|SignatureScheme.java:412|Ignore disabled signature scheme: rsa_md5
2023-08-23 13:14:20.524,"javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-08-23 13:14:20.523 GMT|SSLExtensions.java:272|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.533,"javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-08-23 13:14:20.533 GMT|SSLExtensions.java:272|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.534,javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-08-23 13:14:20.533 GMT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:661|No session to resume.
2023-08-23 13:14:20.534,"javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-08-23 13:14:20.534 GMT|SSLExtensions.java:272|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-08-23 13:14:20.541 GMT|ClientHello.java:641|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"""ClientHello"": {"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"  ""client version""      : ""TLSv1.2"","
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"  ""random""              : ""5343023433CFCA8CAB3D6C3551F79C03817BD0BEBB11679D1587FF1BEC8C1B00"","
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"  ""session id""          : ""7092A57911F65CC5D96FF148FDFEE5BAFA63ACDE2A65AA27B504C6A3294D02E6"","
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"  ""cipher suites""       : ""[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCAA), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]"","
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"  ""compression methods"" : ""00"","
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"  ""extensions""          : ["
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"    ""server_name (0)"": {"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"      type=host_name (0), value=outboundproxy.example.domain"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"    },"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"    ""status_request (5)"": {"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"      ""certificate status type"": ocsp"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"      ""OCSP status request"": {"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"        ""responder_id"": <empty>"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"        ""request extensions"": {"
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,          <empty>
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,        }
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,      }
2023-08-23 13:14:20.542,"    }
...
```

some config info:

```
quarkus.http.http2=false
quarkus.http.proxy.proxy-address-forwarding=true
quarkus.oidc.enabled=true
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${keycloakAuthServerUrl}/realms/${keycloakRealm}
quarkus.oidc.discovery-enabled=true
quarkus.oidc.client-id=${keycloakResource}
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=${keycloakCredentialsSecret}
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none
quarkus.oidc.proxy.host=${squidProxyHost}
quarkus.oidc.proxy.port=${squidProxyPort}
```

Edited with answer based on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26577

my ${squidProxyHost} was outboundproxy.example.domain because of keycloak authorization components that separated scheme from host.  I updated

```
quarkus.oidc.proxy.host=${squidProxyHost}
to 
quarkus.oidc.proxy.host=http://${squidProxyHost}
```

Comment: We are discussing it, thanks

Comment: FYI, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35556

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/2468